# What other uses are there for pull-back motors?

Tags: technic, piece-usage

Sets 42010 and 42011 feature [a pull-back motor](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=12787c01&in=S). They have a very high torque for a very small numbers of turns, they then free-wheel.

I'm trying to find alternate usage for them. That is anything but connecting them directly to the wheels without gears, as putting any gear demultiplication is great while the motor is turning, but it quickly prevents the vehicle moving when free wheeling.

What I've managed to do so far:

- Using it to launch a spinning top
- Launch a rotor blade

Anything else ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yoshihito Isogawa made clock mechanisms from it (well... tic-tac generators) http://www.isogawastudio.co.jp/legostudio/modelgallery_model/b077.html
and http://www.isogawastudio.co.jp/legostudio/modelgallery_model/b078.html.

Majorna created a "programmable" pull back racer http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=69748&#entry1744425

...and another clock by neomomonga: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3-CDFw4O38

Comment: The clock ! that's obvious now that you mention it !

Answer (score 7):

Just today I tried to use it quite successfully as an alternative to suspension springs. Right now I don't have it assembled so I can't post a screenshot, but the idea is to wind up the pullback motor then attach it to your construction with a cross axis from one side and beams from another and limit its moving with some details. If you are interested in how I have done it, I will assemble it to demo and post images.

Comment: An interesting application to be sure :)

Comment: that doesn't work with all pullback motors. Some need less turns to wind up than they provide when turning back.

Answer (score 3):

Once I built a hand-powered semi-automated screwdriver toy for kids. They needed to "charge it" first by rotating a gear and then push a button to release power. Then they could apply it to a crane or other models.

Answer (score 3):

Build a catapult with it. The catapult arm would be attached to the motor. Pulling the arm down will wind the motor

Answer (score 0):

I built a ball launcher out of one. Kind of like a baseball launcher.

Comment: Hi Alex and welcome to Bricks.SE! Your ball launcher sounds interesting, could you please post a picture of it?